# Create new module position in Joomla 3

Tags: php, css, joomla

So I want to create a new module position in Joomla 3! I know you add the position name in the templateDetails.xml of the file. But what next? Do I need to add css to the styling of the template? Also what next, do I need to add more code to the index.php file or how can I do this? I have searched the web for some help but it seems as if the tutorials havn't been updated because some of the files they are describing, like for example lib/framework, I don't have that in my template? ANy help greatly appreciated!

---

[image: templateDetails.xml]

[image: index.php]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure i got your problem properly, but
if you want to just **create module position**, you need to do 2 steps: define position in templateDetails.xml and insert `jdoc:include` code in template's index.php like you did in your code above, thats all. By doing this you define positions where your modules could be displayed.
Then if you want to **add module**, you should go to Joomla administrator panel -> module manager and create module, choosing position you created.

Comment: Thanks Eugene! Yeah, I just wanted to know is this all the code I needed, or will I have to edit the ccs file to position the 'position'?

Comment: Your module's template will appear right where you placed your jdoc:include. If you are not going to change your module visually thats all, otherwise you can edit css file.